# Zend Image upload and generating thumbnails on fly

Tags: zend-framework, file-upload, thumbnails, gdata

I am a php programmer, but new to zend framework. 
I want to upload image, create medium and small(thubmnail) image on fly, I passed a couple of hours searching for a php library [ compatible with zend ] that can make my tasks easy. I dont want to write the code that already exists. thanks for any help.

I want also to know wether Zend_GData can be used to upload files to my server and not on google's. If tried that hack, please tell me how you did it.

any link, or suggestion is welcome. thanks and have a great day.

Comment: In a couple of hours you would have made the php code to generate thumbnails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload I use:
http://www.uploadify.com/

To manipulate images (resize, crop, lots of stuff) I use GD wich is often installed with php.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

I also use http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/ and its real easy to use.

With all that you should be set.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and links, I will be trying them asa I get off the office, thanks again.